# set up SSL for SVN source control

Tags: svn, https, collabnet

I'm configuring CollabNet SVN server (http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/) on windows server 2008 machine. It works fine with http configuration. But when i enable https and attach ssl certificate to it, I can't start the SVN server.

I think, its because of the port issue. I can run SVN server on port 8080 fine (http://domainname:8080/), but when i change the port to 80 it says - 'The server could not bind to port "80". Check permission to use the port and that another process is not using the port.'
I checked binding of port and it's not been used by any other process. So port 80 doesn't work and i can't use https on port 8080.

So just wondering if anyone has seen this issue before and know any possible solution for this.

Thanks.

Comment: Tip: You may want to look at [Visual SVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/). This installs SVN Server for you in a very nice, clean installer. It will setup SSL for you, and creates an MMC snapin for managing repositories. Best of all, there is a free edition that does all of that.

Comment: Is IIS installed on that Server? If so - a website might be bound to port 443. Apache and IIS cannot share ports, so you will have to either free up the port or use a different one for SSL.

Comment: Thanks for response. yes, IIS does exist on this server. But i'm using different IPs for SVN server and other websites.

Answer (score 1):

If you enable the SSL options Apache will try and use port 443 by default it should be trying to use port 80 for non SSL traffic. If as you say, you have IIS installed it is probably grabbing port 80 and 443. As far as I'm aware it is the port you are grabbing on the network card not the IP address - I could be wrong though!  You could trying installing another network card and setting up the apache IP on that or disabling / removing IIS  or trying to use a different port than 443 for SSL to this site.

Alternatively, if you are using the Subversion Edge for Visual Studio (most versions including 2010 both VB and C#) development, can you access the admin console from another machine? 
Should be on something like https://:4434/csvn (if SSL enabled)
or http://:3343/csvn (non SSL) If so,  you could use the AnkhSVN plugin to Visual Studio (also from Collabnet) which allows you to access your repository directly in Visual Studio. It goes through the SubversionEdge Admin URL to access the repository.